# How to Properly Set Permissions for a Custom Strapi Plugin

Tags: plugins, next.js, permissions, strapi

- Strapi Version: 4.1.5
- Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9
- Database: PostgreSQL 13
- Node Version: v14.16.0
- NPM Version: 6.14.11
- Yarn Version: v1.22.5

Hi everyone, I can’t seem to find consistent information on how to use permissions with a custom plugin in Strapi. I want to make an endpoint available to my front-end (Next.JS) application, but only when the front-end application has authenticated as a user and using the JWT that is returned from authenticating with Strapi. I keep getting a 401 returned.

**Here’s what I’m doing:**

I used [this page](https://strapi.io/blog/implementing-authenticated-api-requests-to-strapi) to set up authentication in Strapi. I have a user created in Strapi, and from the front-end, I can authenticate and it returns a JWT token. When I set up collection types to only be accessible with the “authenticated” role, I can access those collection types in the api using this JWT token. So all of that works. The problem is that I can’t get this to work with my custom plugin, and I’m not sure why. I still get a 401 error instead.

**Here’s how I set up the permissions:**

Based on [this page](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/policies.html#implementation), I initially tried to leverage the *isAuthenticated* permission that the Users & Permissions plugin provides:

```
  {
    method: "GET",             
    path: "/progress",
    handler: "memberProgress.getProgress",
    config: {
        policies: ['plugins::users-permissions.isAuthenticated']
    },
  },
```

Unfortunately, this did not work. The server raised an error, saying that this could not be found. So back on the document linked above, I decided to take the approach of creating my own gloabl permission. I created *src/policies/is-authenticated.js* with the following contents:

```
module.exports = (policyContext, config, { strapi }) => {
  if (policyContext.state.user) { // if a session is open
    // go to next policy or reach the controller's action
    return true;
  }

  return false; // If you return nothing, Strapi considers you didn't want to block the request and will let it pass
};
```

Then, I modified my plugin’s route as follows:

```
  {
    method: "GET",             
    path: "/progress",
    handler: "memberProgress.getProgress",
    config: {
        policies: ['global::is-authenticated']
    },
  },
```

This is all based on that document I linked to. Unfortunately, this still does not work. It seems to find the permission (server doesn’t raise an error about it), but when I try to access my plugin’s endpoint with the JWT token, I just get a 401 error.

**Here is how I’m trying to access the endpoint on the front-end:**

```
  // VERIFIED, auth works and I get the expected jwt
  const strapiAuth = await strapiApiAuth();  

  if ( strapiAuth && strapiAuth.hasOwnProperty("jwt") ) {
    
    try {      
      const response = await axios.get( 
        `${process.env.STRAPI_BACKEND_URL}/member-progress/progress?year=2022&name=&pageSize=10&page=1`,
        {
          headers: {           
            Accept: "application/json",                                                                                                                                                                            
            Authorization: `Bearer ${strapiAuth.jwt}`
          },                   
          timeout: 500,        
        }
      );
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      // This is where I land with the 401 error
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Strapi check if you have a valid jwt by default with "authenticated" role, but you must mark the permission to your custom endpoint in "Settings→User & Permission Plugin→Roles" of admin panel also.